# change path size on click to zoom d3.js

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, path, click, zooming

I'm a beginner on D3.js, and a have a project to build a map which uses a click-to-zoom function on countries, based on the example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590). It works perfectly especially for rescaling borders, but I have trouble on dealing with the size of my path points (used for GeoJSON data in entrance), which appear to be enormous when clicking to zoom. 
The example in image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1BgE.png)

I saw many discussions which had the same problem, but with circles and not paths, and it doesn't seem to be the same issue for coding.

Here is the source code I use :

```
var startYear = 1990,
currentYear = startYear;

const width = 960, height = 600;

const path = d3.geoPath();

const projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .center([2.5, 46.5])
  .scale(1000)
  .translate([width/2, height/2]);

path.projection(projection);

const svg = d3.select('#carte')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const pays = svg.append("g");
pays.selectAll("path")
  .data(geojson_pays.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", "#e6e6e6")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("stroke", "#fff")
  .on("click", clicked);

const villes = svg.append("g");
villes.selectAll("path")
  .data(geojson_villes.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .style("stroke-linecap", "square");

const capitales = svg.append("g");
capitales.selectAll("path")
  .data(geojson_capitales.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 3);

villes.selectAll("path").filter(function(d) {
  return d.properties.nom != "NULL";
  }).on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .style("fill", "blue")
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", 1.5)
.style("cursor", "pointer");
}).on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .style("fill", "black")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
tooltip.transition()    
        .duration(500)    
        .style("opacity", 0);
}).on("click",function(d){
tooltip.html(d.properties.nom + "<br />Date : " + d.properties.date);
})

function clicked(d) {
 var bounds = path.bounds(d),
  dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
  dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
  x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
  y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
  scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
  translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  pays.selectAll("path").transition().duration(750).style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale 
  +"px").style("width", 1.5 / scale + "px").style("height", 1.5 / scale + "px").attr("transform", 
  "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  villes.selectAll("path").transition().duration(750).style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + 
  "px").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  capitales.selectAll("path").transition().duration(750).style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + 
  "px").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  }
```

I will be very thankful for a solution in return !

Answer (score 1):

By using the function path.pointradius, I managed to do so actually.
Such as in the function clicked, in the selectAll("path") part add :

```
.attr("d", path.pointRadius(2))
```

To obtain at zoom selected a 2px large path.